# How do i omit some languages from sublimetext2?

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2

I'm using [sublimetext2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), I used sublimetext v1 and it had this option to edit the languages that it display's, in the second version I cant find the option, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution although it's not optimal, you can basically move the language files in the /sublimetext/Pristine Packages to another folder the languages disappear, i would much rather having a config file with an option to white-list the languages i use on a day to day basis to be on the list.
does anyone have a better solution?